# TFS2010: Need the Absolute Path of the Source Directory

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfsbuild

I am invoking VSDBCMD.EXE in my build process template, there is a custom setvar parameter that requires a reference to the current source directory, passing this path has become an unexpected challenge.

I've tried using relative paths and `$(SourceDirectory)` to no avail (it remains as the literal string `"$(SourceDirectory)"` when I see the debug output), the parameter needs an absolute path.

Is there any way to get the absolute path for the current source directory when the script runs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the DefaultTemplate build workflow there is a variable called SourcesDirectory that contains the absolute path.

If you pass it to an InvokeProcess you just type the variable name in the activity property, no $() around it.

Comment: I tried that but it expanded as $(SourceDirectory) and not the absolute path

Comment: Run the Build in Diagnostic logging mode (one of the parameters when you queue a build).  Then examine the build output for the Run On Agent -> Initialize Variables -> Initialize Sources Directory activity.  It should show in the log what it's setting the value to.

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth checking out [this](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2010/01/04/deploy-a-database-project-with-tfs-build-2010/) resource, where author makes use of `ConvertWorkspaceItem` within his build in order to pass in a string the disk location of a know target in source control